# ESP32 BLE Arduino And getting a compile error of 'ringbuf_type_t' has not been declared

Tags: arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy, esp32, arduino-esp32

when i install Arduino IDE and install all the library carefully after that i install ESP32 BLE Arduino library successfully and click on file< Example< ESP32 BLE Arduino < BLE_notify add the code and select a board ESP32 dev module and compile the this through Compiler error

```
In file included from C:\Users\91790\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ESP32_BLE_Arduino\src/BLEAdvertising.h:15,
                 from C:\Users\91790\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ESP32_BLE_Arduino\src/BLEServer.h:19,
                 from C:\Users\91790\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ESP32_BLE_Arduino\src/BLEDevice.h:18,
                 from C:\Users\91790\AppData\Local\Temp\.arduinoIDE-unsaved2024226-8956-kx46nz.zeoqg\BLE_notify\BLE_notify.ino:22:
C:\Users\91790\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ESP32_BLE_Arduino\src/FreeRTOS.h:61:28: error: 'ringbuf_type_t' has not been declared
  Ringbuffer(size_t length, ringbuf_type_t type = RINGBUF_TYPE_NOSPLIT);
                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Using library ESP32 BLE Arduino at version 1.0.1 in folder: C:\Users\91790\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ESP32_BLE_Arduino 
exit status 1

Compilation error: exit status 1
```

when i install Arduino IDE and install all the library carefully after that i install ESP32 BLE Arduino library successfully and click on file< Example< ESP32 BLE Arduino < BLE_notify add the code and select a board ESP32 dev module and compile the this through Compiler error